# How to handle multiple ref cursors in data set ? (Birt Report Design)

Tags: birt

My data set (created using oracle procedure) returns "multiple ref cursors" . In this case birt is displaying all output columns together and it is difficult to identify which column belongs to which ref cursor and if there are any columns with same name in both output cursors , it displays only one. Is there any way to handle this ? or how we handle a data set which contains multiple ref cursors in output ??

Comment: I don't think this is supported. How do you think *should* this work at all? For example, if there are several cursors, each of them could have a different number of rows. Personally, I would reconsider the programming design. You could write a wrapper PL/SQL package that uses the output of your procedure, with one function for each cursor.

Comment: Exactly , i tried it by giving distinct name for  all columns , e.g. c1_col1 , c2_col2 .. etc . But now  the problem is no of rows displayed.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question what you would expect for the number of rows returned. E.g c1 returns 10 rows, c2 returns 15 rows, how many rows should the DS return? You see, it makes no sense.